# glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server

Tags: mount, glusterfs, cluster-shared-volumes

I have a GlusterFS volume hosted on a remote fileserver. I can mount the volume from my webservers in the same DC as well as other servers in other DCs however when I try to mount the volume on my local dev server the mount fails with the following log entry:

```
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.034956] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2018:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.6.2 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=eros --volfile-id=/storage /var/storage)
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.065574] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1494:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.065650] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1596:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:/storage)
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.065889] W [glusterfsd.c:1194:cleanup_and_exit] (--> 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.065905] I [fuse-bridge.c:5599:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/storage'.
[2015-02-04 15:02:56.081713] W [glusterfsd.c:1194:cleanup_and_exit] (--> 0-: received signum (15), shutting down
```

I've verified that the firewall is not blocking the packets, all machines are running the same version of GlusterFS from the same repo and I can telnet to the gluster ports from the local server but I'm still unable to mount the volume on any machines within my local network.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

You must provide the VOLUME NAME in the mount command, not the PATH.

Comment: ... so when `gluster volume info` has lines `Volume Name: gv0` and `Brick1: 192.168.225.5:/export/gvA` then it is `mount -t glusterfs 192.168.225.5:gv0 /mnt/foo` and *not* `mount -t glusterfs 192.168.225.5:/export/gvA /mnt/foo`

Answer (score 6):

If you are *not* using RPM packages it is possible you are experiencing this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1191176

> The names of volfiles on disk was changed for improved rdma support.
> This change was introduced in 3.6.2.
>
> stop glusterd, run `glusterd --xlator-option *.upgrade=on -N` to regenerate the volfiles, start glusterd (on all nodes).

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue today, I have ssl enabled for clients and servers. In my case I had not set the secure-access option on the client (making it use the glusterfs.ca file in /etc/ssl/)

To solve do this:

```
touch /var/lib/glusterd/secure-access
```

Answer (score 1):

## Upgrade your volume

Tested on Proxmox (debian based), GlusterFS 3.8.8, (since 3.6.2)

#### Stop the service

```
service glusterfs-server stop
```

#### Upgrade the volume

```
glusterd -N "--xlator-option=*.upgrade=on"
```

The `xlator-option` expects an `=` and the full option has to be quoted to avoid any globbing to occurs. It's for translator options regarding volume file.

`-N` means the process will run in foreground. Handy if you want to see any errors.

#### Restart service

```
service glusterfs-server start
```

#### Mount the drive

```
 mount -t glusterfs [machine]:[volume-name] [mount-point]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. You saved me hours of time on a Saturday afternoon OS upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this command helps me:

`gluster volume sync <HOSTNAME> [all|<VOLNAME>] - sync the volume information from a peer`